PIC 18F4550 Monitor Serial
PIC18F4550
#include <18F4550.h>                    // Include the microcontroller library
#use delay(clock=48MHz, crystal)        // Define oscillator type and frequency

#build(reset=0x02000, interrupt=0x02008) // Assign reset and interrupt vectors
#org 0x0000, 0x1FFF {}                   // Reserve memory for bootloader version
#fuses HSPLL, CPUDIV1, NOWDT, NOPROTECT, PLL5, NODEBUG, USBDIV, VREGEN

#include <usb_cdc.h>                     // USB-CDC library

void main(void) {
   usb_cdc_init();                       // Configure virtual port
   usb_init();                           // Initialize USB stack

   // Main loop
   while (1) {
      usb_task();                        // Keep USB stack active

      // Send message via USB-CDC
      printf(usb_cdc_putc, "Hola mundo, ¿cómo estás?\n");
      delay_ms(4000);                    // Wait 4 seconds before sending again
   }
}


Help Connecting PIC18F4550 to Serial Monitor Using CCS C Compiler
Question:
I need help connecting my PIC18F4550 microcontroller to a serial monitor. I’ve tried multiple tutorials, but can’t get a stable connection. The code prints text to the monitor, but the output is cut off, and I don’t see the full message.


Start with ASCII only "Hola mundo 12345 67890?\n")  2) Report exact output seen.


"but the output is cut off, and I don’t see the full message." Please show the output you see.

I have realized that something is wrong because when I set this condition !usb_cdc_connected() never detects it as true

I have the CCS C compiler bootloader loaded, it is the software I am using

this is how it prints 10:58:35.518 -> Hola mundo 12345 67890?
10:58:39.381 -> Hola mundo 12345 67890?
10:58:43.410 -> Ha mun 1234578?
10:58:47.409 -> Ha mundo 12345 67890?
10:58:51.383 -> Ha mundo 12345 6789Ha mundo 12345 67890?
10:58:59.386 -> Ha mundo 12345 67890?
10:59:03.422 -> H mundo 12345 67890?
10:59:07.411 -> Ha 34670?
10:59:11.421 -> Ha mundo23 67890H mundo 12345 67890?
10:59:19.407 -> H mundo 12345 67890?
10:59:23.437 -> H mundo 12345 67890?
10:59:27.427 -> Ha mundo 12345 67890?
10:59:31.424 -> H mundo 123 67890?

@PUENTEELIZONDOJESUSEDUARDO don't post complementary information in comments, it's hard to read. Instead [edit] the question and put all relevant information into the question.
